# Configure phantomjs to work with webpack and karma nwb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, karma-runner, nwb

I am using nwb to configure a react app, I would use like to `chai` and `enzyme` to set up my testing environment. I have made the following changes to accomplish this, I created a `tests.webpack.js` file:

```
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiEnzyme from 'chai-enzyme';
import chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';
import sinonChai from 'sinon-chai';

chai.use(chaiEnzyme());
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
chai.use(sinonChai);

const context = require.context('./src', true, /\.spec\.js/);
context.keys.forEach(context);
```

I also modified the karma config in `nwb.config.js`:

```
const karmaChaiPlugins = require('karma-chai-plugins');

module.exports = {
  type: 'react-component',
  npm: {
    esModules: true,
    umd: {
      global: 'ReactMg',
      externals: {
        react: 'React',
      },
    },
  },
  karma: {
    testContext: 'tests.webpack.js',
    plugins: [
      karmaChaiPlugins,
    ],
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'chai-as-promised'],
  },
  webpack: {
    compat: {
      enzyme: true,
      sinon: true,
    },
  },
};
```

I get an error when running `nwb test` after defining `index.spec.js` in `src`:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'context.keys.forEach(context)')
  at tests.webpack.js:73
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.375 secs / 0 secs)
Karma exit code was 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix error **TypeError: undefined is not a function**

You should change `context.keys.forEach(context);`  on `context.keys().forEach(context);` because `keys` is function[1]

[1] - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: The amount of time I spent on this issue is too high, dont know how I missed that. Thanks @maksimr